# Name this data-structure: array that compacts all contents towards the front

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, data-structures, vector

Picture an array with random access, such that if you remove one object from the array, all others after it are moved forward.

For example, say our array is of length five, but only contains 3 items, like so:

[A,B,C,null,null]

If we remove B, C is automatically moved forward resulting in:

[A,C,null,null,null]

Is there a common name for such a datastructure? Bonus upvote if you can name an existing mechanism in JavaScript/JQuery :)

Comment: You described a vector in C++. Vectors can also be resized.

Comment: I don't believe vector will automatically compact objects towards the front. What I described is more like a linked list with random access.

Comment: Whoops - you're right. the erase() method does shift objects forward.

Comment: Yep :) That's why you don't want to use vectors if you're adding/removing items from the middle unless there aren't any better options

Comment: What is this, a game show?  It's called an array that compacts all its contents towards the front.

Comment: Haha - I want to know because it makes it more searchable and easier to discuss. Is this the definition of vector, or is that just the C++ implementation?

Comment: I think it was originally just the C++ implementation, but at this point it's basically become the definition of a vector, at least in programming circles. Mathematicians and engineers use a different definition.

Comment: The data structure is an [`array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), particularly a dense array, the mechanism for removing items from the middle (or anywhere) and keeping it dense is [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: To keep the `length` you need [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add the number of `null`s to the end of the `array`. This number is returned by `splice`

Comment: To have this all happen "magically", you will have to create your own `object`.

Comment: Technically you're correct - but I'm interested in a specialized data-structure because of the runtime considerations that come up with the random removal and shifting of other elements. I wondered if this was a named data-structure so that I could easily find such work: an array or vector includes a number of other features that may interfere with a pure data-structure as I described.

Comment: There is no native structure in javascript that acts as you have described.Otherwise I guess it could be called a "fixed length buffer normally populated with null".

Comment: Yeah. I should not have added the JavaScript part - I was primarily interested in finding nomenclature so I could study the mechanism, just got greedy hoping for a JS implementation at the same time.

Comment: The amount of confusion I've generated makes it clear my question was poorly formed from the start. My apologies. Thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to be glib but isn't the data structure just an array? You would use the `slice` method to remove the element and `push` to add the null value to the end.

Comment: As I commented elsewhere, this is correct- but I specifically state that I'm looking for a data-structure because I want to know what kinds of performance optimizations have been done. If it is a named data-structure, then there is research surrounding it. An array with slice/splice method may have the same functionality, but could perform much differently than a data-structure designed only for the functions I described. Thank you nonetheless!

Comment: I'm a little confused. When you say, "this is correct- but I specifically state that I'm looking for a data-structure..." and "If it is a named data-structure..." are you implying that an array is not a data structure? An array is a named data structure. I'm sure there is research and documentation regarding the efficiency of various JS interpreter array and slice/push method implementations.

Comment: I apologize - the amount of confusion I've generated makes it clear my question was poorly formed from the start. Thanks for providing a mechanism as I asked - I'm marking this correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you told me that you had a list that compacts its items toward the front as you describe, I would assume that it's a sorted list, or a list in which order matters. For example, when items are added they're always appended, so the items remain in their insertion order.

If order doesn't matter, then it's more efficient to replace the deleted item with the last item in the list. That is, given `[A,B,C,D,null,null]` and you delete B, you end up with `[A,D,C,null,null,null]`.

Comment: That's exactly right. Insertion order matters, so it's similar to a stack/queue in that sense - but with random access.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example of a custom object to do what you describe could be something like this.

Javascript

```
var MyBuffer = (function () {
    'use strict';

    /*jslint bitwise: true */
    var MAX_LENGTH = Math.pow(2, 32),
        MAX_LAST = MAX_LENGTH - 1,
        toStringFN = {}.toString,
        sliceFN = [].slice,
        toObject = {}.constructor;

    function isNumber(inputArg) {
        return toStringFN.call(inputArg) === '[object Number]';
    }

    function isString(inputArg) {
        return toStringFN.call(inputArg) === '[object String]';
    }

    function clamp(value, max) {
        return Math.min(Math.max(value, 0), max) >>> 0;
    }

    function fillHoles(array, length, value) {
        var index;

        for (index = 0; index < length; index += 1) {
            if (!array.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
                array[index] = value;
            }
        }

        return array;
    }

    function isNumeric(inputArg) {
        return (isNumber(inputArg) || isString(inputArg)) &&
            !isNaN(parseFloat(inputArg)) && isFinite(inputArg.toString().replace(/^-/, ''));
    }

    function checkType(inputArg) {
        if (!isNumeric(inputArg)) {
            throw new TypeError();
        }

        return inputArg;
    }

    function checkRange(value, max) {
        if (value < 0 && value > max) {
            throw new RangeError();
        }

        return value;
    }

    function ABuffer() {
        var args;

        if (!arguments.length) {
            this.buffer = [];
            this.length = 0;
            this.filler = null;
        } else {
            args = sliceFN.call(arguments);
            if (args.length === 1) {
                this.filler = null;
            } else {
                this.filler = args[1];
            }

            if (isNumeric(args[0])) {
                this.buffer = [];
                this.length = clamp(args[0], MAX_LENGTH);
            } else {
                this.buffer = sliceFN.call(toObject(args[0]));
                this.length = this.buffer.length;
            }
        }

        fillHoles(this.buffer, this.length, this.filler);
    }

    ABuffer.prototype = {
        clear: function () {
            this.buffer.length = 0;
            this.buffer.length = this.length;
            fillHoles(this.buffer, this.buffer.length, this.filler);

            return this;
        },

        resize: function (length) {
            checkRange(checkType(length), MAX_LAST);
            this.buffer.length = length = clamp(length, MAX_LENGTH);
            if (length > this.length) {
                fillHoles(this.buffer, this.buffer.length, this.filler);
            }

            this.length = length;

            return this;
        },

        assign: function (index, value) {
            var last = this.length - 1;

            checkRange(checkType(index), last);
            this.buffer[clamp(index, last)] = value;

            return this;
        },

        remove: function (index, howMany) {
            var last = this.length - 1,
                count;

            checkRange(checkType(index), last);
            count = this.buffer.splice(clamp(index, last), clamp(howMany, this.length) || 1).length;
            while (count) {
                this.buffer.push(this.filler);
                count -= 1;
            }

            return this;
        },

        item: function (index) {
            var last = this.length - 1;

            checkRange(checkType(index), last);

            return this.buffer[clamp(index, last)];
        },

        toString: function () {
            return JSON.stringify(this.buffer);
        },

        valueOf: function () {
            return this.buffer.slice();
        }
    };

    return ABuffer;
}());

var buffer = new MyBuffer({
    0: 'A',
    1: 'B',
    2: 'C',
    length: 5
});

/*global console */
console.log(buffer.toString());
buffer.remove(1, 2);
console.log(buffer.toString());
buffer.assign(3, 'X');
console.log(buffer.toString());
buffer.resize(10);
console.log(buffer.toString());
buffer.resize(5);
console.log(buffer.toString());
buffer.clear();
console.log(buffer.toString());
```

Output

```
["A","B","C",null,null]
["A",null,null,null,null]
["A",null,null,"X",null]
["A",null,null,"X",null,null,null,null,null,null]
["A",null,null,"X",null]
[null,null,null,null,null]
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7ztcf/)

Comment: Thanks, Xotic750, this may come in handy. I apologize for the confusion in the comments - I did not word this question well.

Comment: Your welcome. I think this is the type of thing that you were after, or close enough to be of use as an example.